# My Python script gets stuck when i load data into CSV from Teradata and won't continue to run

Tags: python, teradata, teradatasql

The script saves the data to a csv file, this is the ***cur.execute*** command, and then nothing happens, just hangs in the same place,
***print(0)*** never prints

***exit()***,***quit()***,***sys.exit()*** does not help

```
import teradatasql


def teradata_to_bigquery_export(bqproject = 'project', tddatabase = 'db', tdtable = 'table',bqdataset = 'dataset', gcpSA = 'key.json', host = 'host', user = 'user', password = 'pwd'):
        print(123)
        # teradata read data and save to dataframe
        with teradatasql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password) as con:
            print(-2)
            with con.cursor() as cur:
                print(-1)
                cur.execute("{fn teradata_try_fastexport}{fn teradata_write_csv(myFile.csv)}SELECT * FROM " + tddatabase + "." + tdtable + " WHERE date_creation = CURRENT_DATE")
                print(0)
                cur.close()
        print(1)
```

Comment: What is the string you send to `cur.execute` supposed to be? In particular, what should be the two double-bracketed strings at the start? And two comments: 1) you don't need triple-quotes when you have only one line; 2) instead of `{tddatabase + '.' + tdtable}` you can write `{tddatabase}.{tdtable}`.

Comment: SQL should look like this:
{fn teradata_try_fastexport}{fn teradata_write_csv(myFile.csv)}SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE date_creation = CURRENT_DATE 
but without the double curly braces the functions don't work, fn are teradata functions. 
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Are you using most recent teradatasql? There were a couple recent fixes around FastExport with Write_CSV.

Comment: i ran pip install teradatasql --upgrade and then ran the code and same problem again

Comment: without {fn teradata_try_fastexport} its worked

Answer (score 0):

We would need to gather a debug log from you for troubleshooting.
Please create a customer incident with Teradata Customer Support.